# How can I include relationships in my Cucumber tests for Hyperledger Composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer, cucumberjs

How can I create relationships between assets when writing tests using Cucumber? I tried:

```
    And I have added the following assets
    | id | rel                       |
    | a  | org.example.OtherAsset#id |
```

but that didn't work, and prefixing it with `resource:` didn't work either.

It works fine when creating assets with JSON, but I feel like this should be possible using the "table" interface too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When including relationships in Cucumber, you do not need to include the relationship's asset type as that is inferred automatically.

The above code works if changed to:

```
And I have added the following assets
| id | rel |
| a  | id  |
```

Comment: exactly. A very simple example can be found in the Composer sample networks repo (there are a few networks with Cucumber tests, such as the basic-sample-network example)  - eg https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/basic-sample-network/features/sample.feature#L30